# Set copied projecttask record as parent of another projecttask

Tags: netsuite

When I try to use the id returned by nlapiSubmitRecord as the parent for another it throws an invalid id.  The copy (after nlapiSubmitRecord) has no id field when examining it in a debug console.

My question is how do I do this, or copy a projecttask and include the children in a suitescript (preferably a client script).

Cheers,
PJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here goes.  An NDA keeps me from posting the code, but I'll document the main sticking point and how to resolve it.  If the parent has the field issummarytask = 'T', the copy of the parent must be created with 0 estimated hours in order to make it a summary task.  it may have estimated hours in its field but those are created by the children.

This was implemented as a user event which adds a button, specifying a client script as the script containing the callback (to deal with the button click), which in turn calls a suitelet that does most of the work.

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

You can only use a Project Task as a parent if it has no resources assigned. 
Otherwise the following works:

```
var subTask = nlapiLoadRecord('projecttask', subTaskId);
subTask.setFieldValue('parent', parentInternalId);
nlapiSubmitRecord(subTask);
```

Where you get your ids for subTaskId and parentInternalId depends on what you are doing. If this doesn't help can you post your code to give some more context to your question?

Comment: Thank you very much for replying!  Having just gone through this with a couple of very experienced Netsuite consultants via a screen-share, and them also noting that the behaviour is bizarre, I'm trying to accomplish it via a chain of suite scripts (suitelets and client scripts) based on their "this might work" suggestions.  I'll post the working solution, and if not, the non-functioning code and some context.

Comment: Partial headway being made.  Any idea why it would throw CYCLE_IN_PROJECT_PLAN in the script when I assign a parent then let me select that parent through the Netsuite interface and have it be just fine?